# Can we have mutilple cloudformation.template depend on a template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, metrics

I want to create a lambda function that will be used by multiple clients. Lambda will be triggered by SQS queue created by clients. Clients will create there own cloudFormation template and will invoke the lambda handler. However, I want to use AWS metric filters for metric creation. Is there any way to maintain same metric filters at multiple cloudFormation template?